# I can't create and using a Package

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Learning_package AS

    PROCEDURE add_person(name_person people.C_Name%type,
    mail_person people.C_mail%type,
    age_person  people.C_age%TYPE);
END Learning_package;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Learning_package AS

    PROCEDURE add_person(name_person  people.C_Name%type,
    mail_person  people.C_mail%type,
    age_person   people.C_age%TYPE)
    IS
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO people (C_Name, C_mail, C_age)
          VALUES (name_person, mail_person, age_person);  
    END add_person;

END Learning_package;

/
BEGIN
    Learning_package.add_person('john', 'fffff@all.com', 20);
END;
```

an error appears:

> package body "Learning_package" has erros PL/SQL: could not find
> program unit being called "Learning_package" at line 3

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can query the `user_errors` view to see the compilation errors for the package specification and/or body. If that doesn't make it clear, please edit the question to show that output, and the definition of the people table. (In what you've shown, if that is all run as a single script then you might just be missing a `/` at the end of the specification; but as the error refers to the body that seems unlikely.)

Comment: PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'add_person' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body

Comment: Then the package specification you actually ran isn't what you showed; [that works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2adef30d73a1b2b465211545fb01ccd4). Compare with what is shown in `user_source`.  Whatever you are actually running has a mismatch. If you created this earlier with a different spec then perhaps that hasn't run properly - again, maybe due to the missing slash.

Comment: Not related to your question, but please allow me to point out an issue with your data design.  You are storing the person's "age".  But their age is constantly increasing.  Are you planning on a daily job to update their age?  And based on what?  Well, of course not.  Instead of storing their "age", you should store the date of birth, as data type DATE.  Then you can always compute their correct age as 'sysdate - date_of_birth'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine except that you need to:

- Make sure that you have a `people` table with the expected columns; and
- Use a `/` statement terminator in a new line at the end of every PL/SQL statement.

Like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Learning_package AS

    PROCEDURE add_person(name_person people.C_Name%type,
    mail_person people.C_mail%type,
    age_person  people.C_age%TYPE);
END Learning_package;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Learning_package AS

    PROCEDURE add_person(name_person  people.C_Name%type,
    mail_person  people.C_mail%type,
    age_person   people.C_age%TYPE)
    IS
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO people (C_Name, C_mail, C_age)
          VALUES (name_person, mail_person, age_person);  
    END add_person;

END Learning_package;
/

BEGIN
    Learning_package.add_person('john', 'fffff@all.com', 20);
END;
/
```

*Note: Age is not a good thing to store as it quickly becomes out-of-date. Instead, you should store date-of-birth and when you need an age you can calculate it from the date-of-birth and today's date.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d8e8c3d3fa6d03ebbd69e20cdd08749f)*

Answer (score 0):

Could you also add a block terminator after the package creation and change the `AS` to `IS` (/).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Learning_package IS

END Learning_package;
/
```

Same goes for the package body.

Comment: The problem is the same

Comment: Did you also put / at the end of the begin end block where you call the procedure?

Comment: AS vs. IS is irrelevant, Oracle supports both.

Comment: Used to do it with AS, never put much though in it